# Is this a good use of an ExtensionMethod?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I just wrote an if statement in the lines of

```
if (value == value1 || value == value2 || value == value3 || value == value4)
    //do something
```

and it annoys me that I always have to repeat the 'value ==' part. In my opinion this is serving no purpose other than making it difficult to read.

I wrote the following ExtensionMethod that should make above scenario more readable:

```
public static bool IsEqualToAny<T>(this T value, params T[] objects)
{
    return objects.Contains(value);
}
```

Now I can simply write

```
if (value.IsEqualToAny(value1, value2, value3, value4))
    //do something
```

Is this a good usage of an ExtensionMethod?

EDIT:

Thanks for all the great answers. For the record: I have kept the method. While the suggestion that you could simply use `new []{value1,value2,value3,value4}.Contains(value)` is true, I simply prefer reading this kind of if statement from left to right (***if this value is equal to any of these*** instead of ***if these values contain this value***). Having one more method show up in intellisense on each object is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't added functionality that is only useful to a specific application or context, your extension is clearly named and the behaviour is obvious without having to look at the implementation.

The answer is "Yes, it is"

Answer (score 5):

It is unusual to write an extension method for an unrestricted `T`. Not least, this approach will quickly make your intellisense quite hard to use.

While valid, I'd probably avoid this *as an extension method* - perhaps just use a standard static utility method.

The C# 3 array initializer syntax might be easier?

```
bool isTrue = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Contains(3);
```

Of course, for large sets of data, you might want to cache a `HashSet<T>` somewhere ;-p

Comment: thanks for the comment Marc.
could you explain why this will make intellisense hard to use?

Comment: Because it'll appear on every single variable when you press ".". It only takes a handful of such methods to start making it hard to find the methods relevant to a type... in reality, you aren't going to want to use this method **that** often (I hope) compared to every other method available.

Comment: I agree - having extension methods for objects or unrestricted generic type parameters is just one step away from having abominations in your code like null.MyExtensionMethod()

Comment: I won't mention the "ThrowIfNull<T> where T : class" extension method (for arg checking), then ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me, although it seems a little unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty fair, but I'd take a step back. Can you put any business meaning in the comparison? What are those values? Maybe you'd be better off with a method called `IsSpecialCustomerLocation` or something that expresses the actual intent of the code.

Comment: thanks. It is fairly generic. I was just comparing an enum value - it was related to GUI programming so it didn't have any business meaning as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LINQ method syntax for that task (by using System.Linq namespace):

```
            object[] objects = new object[10];
        objects.Contains(new MyClass());
```

Hmm let me think an moment... Oh you already using it. But you have put it in a separate method instead of calling it directly.

Comment: the array initializer syntax would be even cleaner... see my post.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a static class for that purpose. I don't like that solution because it adds a method to all classes which seems a bit overkill. However it does in a way go with OOD because you ask the objects to perform functions on themselves (kinda).

Still, I would go with a reusable class instead because I can see how an antipattern could form. I'm not calling it an antipattern yet, but if too many of those constructs pop up I would call that an antipattern of readability since every object would get cluttered with extension methods. I kinda look at it like namespace pollution, but class member pollution.

```
if (ConditionHelper.IsEqualToAny(value, value1, value2, value3)) 
{
    // Do something
}
```

Does the same job and doesn't pollute anything.

Comment: Coming to think of it, it suffers of a little readability problem. It has to do with that it isn't obvious that value is checked against value1, value2, value3 and so forth. value.IsEqualToAny(value1, value2, value3) does have a better readability. My concern was only about polluting members.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really intending to do Contains and guarantee you will be applying Contains on **all possible objects** where you might use this extension method?

If some given objects test equality by overloading operator== then your generic solution will fail. That makes it not a true equivalent of the multiple == tests. It is also a good example of the danger of writing extension methods!

The following Linq code works when you implement operator overloading as well as if you are using the default == meaning of comparing object references, to say that value is actually the same object as value1, 2, 3 or 4, given V as the object type of your values in this particular case:

```
V[] lv = { value, value2, value3, value4 };
if (lv.Any( v => v==value))
   // do something
```

Or a short-hand version:

```
if (new List<V>{value, value2, value3, value4 }.Any( v => v==value))
   // do something
```

I couldn't get the above lambda expressions to work in a generic extension method.

As a good (if irrelevant) example of what I think is a lovely, readable syntax, the idiom in Python would be

```
if value in (value1, value2, value3, value4):
```

Comment: I don't see how this is an issue. The Contains method (which is an ExtensionMethod (implemented in System.Linq.Enumerable)) uses an EqualityComparer which (in the default case) uses a == comparison.

Comment: Maybe I implemented it wrongly or there is something about the way it is bound but when I test it the extension method fails to detect an object which is a different object but equal based on its operator== overloading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only checking an Enum value (as you said in the comment on Rogers answer), you should use a [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) on the Enum.

```
[Flags]
public enum Value
{
  Value1 = 0,
  Value2 = 1,
  Value3 = 2,
  Value4 = 4
}

Value value = Value.Value1;
if (value | Value.Value1 | Value.Value2 | Value.Value3 | Value.Value4)
{
  // You can also use other bitwise operations, like & (AND), ^ (XOR) and ~ (NOT)
}
```

Otherwise; if it is domain specific, add it to your business logic. If it's generic, create a helper class.

Comment: I don't think that would be appropriate. Only because I want to check for a number of different values doesn't mean that the enum should be a bit field. I don't want the enum value to be a combined value. - thanks for your input though. I have been using this extension method for a while now and it has been quite useful in a number of situations.